# C++ Why is it illegal to reverse a path?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    std::experimental::filesystem::path str("fffff/aaaa/.");    
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using vs2015 ,and this code above doesn't compile ,but I can still reverse a string .

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    std::string str("fffff/aaaa/.");    
    std::reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Why ?

Comment: What error message do you get? I don't have MSVC here, and my compiler complains about <filesystem>.

Comment: you need `<experimental/filesystem>`

Comment: Pro tip: correctly reversing a string is way more complicated than what you have here.

Comment: Since path has syntax, what would its reversal mean?

Comment: with boost::filesystem::path, the compiler complains that the iterators are forward iterators and not bidirectional iterators ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9f597f1ca2c329)).  Since the question is about C++17 and the filesystem is experimental, I don't think this is the place to discuss why. It is a bit unfortunate that path doesn't behave more like a string

Comment: If you want to do stringy things with a path, use one of its string() methods.

Comment: And the why is: a path iterator walks the path's components, not the letters of its string representation. Some of those have a fixed location (i.e. drive letter needs to come first). So, a generic reverse algorithm does not apply.

Comment: I can't think of a single situation where reversing a file system path would be useful.

Comment: @Mehrdad What is the issue with the string reversal shown?

Comment: @juanchopanza: [multi-byte characters/Unicode/accents/etc.](https://discuss.fogcreek.com/techinterview/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=2780)... for example if you have A-[accent]-C then the accent will be on the wrong letter if you change that to C-[accent]-A.

Comment: @Mehrdad For multi-byte characters, I am not sure `std::string` is a good choice anyway.

Comment: @molbdnilo Haha, I have a map ,using paths as keys and file contents as values. I want to look up the file contents using paths or filenames ,like "find out the file: ./image/logo.png" ,or "lookup all files named logo.png",

Comment: @iouvxz How does reversing a path have anything to do with that?

Comment: @molbdnilo So I reverse the paths ,compare them and insert the paths and files to the map ,so that files with the same filename will be contiguous .I can use equal range to look them up .

Comment: @molbdnilo Paths are unique ,reverse paths are still unique ,so I can still access the files by reversing the full path and look up the key .

Comment: @iouvxz It sound like you should be using a `std::multimap` with a suitable custom comparison, or a class of your own which has a path member, instead of abusing the concept of file path.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't need to ,I using something like auto comp = [](path a,path b){return rev(a.wstring())<rev(b.wstring());} as my map predict . Paths are always unique ,I don't need a multimap .

Comment: @juanchopanza: I named more things than multi-byte characters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not compile as `path::begin()` and `path::end()` returns `path::iterator` which is an alias for `path::const_iterator`.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza Because reverse was implemented using swap .

Comment: @iouvxz The point is that if it is implemented with `const_iterator`, it is for a reason. It is not an oversight. So the question of "why?" still remains.